# Поиск подстроки в строке на php через регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно получить строку 5211090321 из строки gid|3119312904|aid|5211090321|11957442335_ средствами php. Не могу разобраться, как искать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обязательно для этого использовать регулярные выражения:

```
$str = 'gid|3119312904|aid|5211090321|11957442335_';

echo explode('|', $str)[3];
```

Результат:

```
5211090321
```

---

Если использование регулярных выражений - обязательное требование, тогда решение можно записать так:

```
$str = 'gid|3119312904|aid|5211090321|11957442335_';

preg_match('~(?:[^|]+\|){3}\K[^|]+~', $str, $arr);

echo $arr[0];
```